# My R data frame has 2 separate tables that sit in the same columns, but the column names are not the same. How can I subset/extract the bottom table?

Tags: r, stringr

I am loading a csv file into R Studio that has two separate tables that fall within the same columns on the file, but the second table has a separate field(column name) that I need to separate and add to the first table (The csv is structured similarly to the code below)

```
    #1| Date | Figure1| Figure2|
    ----------------------------
    #2|1/1/20|   10   |   15   |
    #3|1/8/20|   20   |   25   |
 ...
 ...
   #56| Date | Figure3|
   --------------------
   #57|1/1/20|   18   |
   #58|1/8/20|   16   |
```

I need a way for R to read all of the rows up until the occurrence of "Total3" in the 2nd columns and put that into its own data frame (df1), as well as read all of the rows after the occurrence of "Total3" in the second columns and separate the into its own data frame (df2) so that I can merge these data frames into one single table. The csv that I am pulling is updated every week so I am unable to hard index the row numbers in order to do this (rows are added to both tables). Ultimately I need it to look something like this.

```
    #1| Date | Figure1| Figure2| Figure3|
    -------------------------------------
    #2|1/1/20|   10   |   15   |   18   |
    #3|1/8/20|   20   |   25   |   16   |
```

I have looked into using stringr's string_extract, but have not been able to make this work for my case, thank you for any help.

Comment: please provide a reprex

Comment: It sounds like you need to go once through the file to locate your target string, then use that value when you actually read in the tables.  as @Bruno mentioned, a reproducible example would get you much better help.